# Dynamic streaming of a video on a website

Tags: javascript, video, streaming

I'd like to publish a video on my website. I use javascript and SWFObject to allow to watch it directly on the website. The format of the video is mp4 and it's quite a big file - let's say about 300MB. Thus, it takes a while until it loads in the player. I'd like the visitors to start watching the video while it's not fully downloaded. In other word, I'd like to stream in the way e.g. Youtube does.

The small example I uploaded there:
http://geoportaltoskania.t15.org/Film360.html

Here you can find all files and codes that are used for this:
http://geoportaltoskania.t15.org

Thanks, Krzychu

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following options:

1) MPEG-Dash - https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/01/03/streaming_video_player/

2) VideoJS - https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md

Answer (score 0):

MPEG-DASH or HLS is a good solution for your problem. You can take your file and transcode it to HLS and MPEG-DASH using e.g. http://www.bitcodin.com, put it on your webserver and playback it with e.g. http://www.dash-player.com